# Visual Studio Code só executa a primeira linha do documento

Tags: visual-studio-code

fala pessoal,

Estou com um problema no Visual Studio Code, ele só executa a primeira linha do meu documento. Para que eu possa executar as demais linhas, eu tenho que selecioná-las, gostaria de achar uma forma de que o documento fosse executado por completo.

Sem selecionar
[image: Sem selecionar]

Selecionando
[image: Selecionando]

Comment: Substitua as imagens pelo seu código.

Comment: Se executar o comando no terminal diretamente funciona como esperado ?

Comment: Vc deve ter ativado ou entrado em algum modo de debug que ele faz breackpints automáticos por linha. Vc pode pesquisar por "vscode auto breakpoints" e ver se tem algo a ver com o seu problema